# Using attributes to cache a method's return results in C#

Tags: c#, .net, caching, attributes

In webmethods, it is very simple to implement caching by annotating [WebMethod(CacheDuration...] attribute. Can we create something similar for non-webmethods, such as Static methods?

Any help/tip is appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious as to why. I don't believe it's possible.

Comment: Alastair, the reason is because I don't want to leave my cache implementation everywhere in my methods. Secondly, I have a bunch of static methods (without static members or context) so having cache implemented for each is very time consuming and messy. I guess I am just looking for an easy way. And Aspects Oriented Programming will help for sure! Thanks everyone.

Comment: @SP. did you come up with any declarative solution for catching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built in feature for achieving exactly what you want. You should use `Httpruntime.Cache`.

It's not a built in feature but you may achieve something like that using aspect oriented programming (AOP). Caching information using aspects.

In case you're interested [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/) provides AOP

Comment: Thanks for replying, Claudio. AoP can help, but it is not possible for the project at this time. So the next best thing is Attribute. Can't we still use HttpRuntime.Cache with attributes? If so, any pointers on how to achieve it?

Comment: @SP: I'm afraid you have to do it programatically, you can't use attributes.

Comment: @SP attributes are nothing more than metadata embedded in the assembly. You'd need something to read that metadata and intercept the method call. This is exactly what AOP does. So an attribute-only solution is impossible.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I have to look into AoP framework. But it will be worth it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2009/01/16/caching-with-c-aop-and-postsharp/) simple implementation of an attribute  for caching using Post Sharp.

Comment: PostSharp is great and does exactly what I want. Great commercial alternative. Thank you, Fernando.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use AOP to get the job done you could try using this little class I put together.

```
public MyClass CachedInstance
{
    get { return _cachedInstance.Value; }
}
private static readonly Cached<MyClass> _cachedInstance = new Cached<MyClass>(() => new MyClass(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));

public sealed class Cached<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T> _createValue;
    private readonly TimeSpan _cacheFor;
    private DateTime _createdAt;
    private T _value;


    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (_createdAt == DateTime.MinValue || DateTime.Now - _createdAt > _cacheFor)
            {
                lock (this)
                {
                    if (_createdAt == DateTime.MinValue || DateTime.Now - _createdAt > _cacheFor)
                    {
                        _value = _createValue();
                        _createdAt = DateTime.Now;
                    }
                }
            }
            return _value;
        }
    }


    public Cached(Func<T> createValue, TimeSpan cacheFor)
    {
        if (createValue == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("createValue");
        }
        _createValue = createValue;
        _cacheFor = cacheFor;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am looking more declarative way to cache, so AoP solutions fit much better. If everything fails, I have to do it the hard way, by leaving cache entrails everywhere. Messy!